# Is it safe to use inline if statements with optional values

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Is it a good idea to use inline if statements on optional values when not changing the value itself: -

```
var optionalValue:[Int]?
var isOptionalValueCount = 0

optionalValue = [4, 5, 6]

if let value = optionalValue {
    isOptionalValueCount = value.count
}

println("amount of integers (using usual syntax): \(isOptionalValueCount)")
// "amount of integers (using usual syntax): 3"

isOptionalValueCount = optionalValue != nil ? optionalValue!.count : 0

println("amount of integers (using inline): \(isOptionalValueCount)")
// "amount of integers (using inline): 3"
```

This makes the code more succinct, however we still have the "!" when calculating the optionalValue.count- to me this seems like a bad code smell.

What are the disadvantages of using the inline if statement to deal with optionals like this?

Comment: Yup, `!` is usually a bad smell.  Whenever you have `thing != nil ? thing : default`, you can use `thing ?? default` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any disadvantage, beside not looking good in my opinion, so I'd prefer the optional binding. However I think you can rewrite that as:

```
isOptionalValueCount = optionalValue?.count ?? 0
```

If `optionalValue` is `nil`, then the left expression evaluates to `nil`, and the nil coalescing operator returns the expression at right.

Comment: Isn't it `isOptionalValueCount = optionalValue?.count ? : 0`?

Comment: @AdamPro13: no, I'm using the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

Comment: Whoops, I was still in Objective-C world. That's a pretty neat operator.

Comment: Yeah it is - I used it for the 1st time in C#, years ago - but in swift, combined with optional chaining, is much more useful